# How can I create json file for following task?

Tags: json, rest

Hi Dear Developers I hope all of you are doing great I am trying to create JSON file using the following requirement by the help of https://www.mocky.io/ but I have never done myself. I am stuck. I mainly used ready JSON API any help will be appreciated.

a. Overview, Education, Work, Skills, Contact.
i. Overview – should contain your picture and your introduction.
ii. Education – should contain your educational background as a list with
necessary details like duration, institution etc.
iii. Work – should contain your work experience with necessary details
like employer, durations etc.
iv. Skills – should contain your area of expertise and other relevant skills.
v. Contact – should contain your contact information and a way to
contact you.
3. Your “Overview” should be served as a dynamic JSON content from a mock api like
https://www.mocky.io/
4. All other data should be served as mock data from json contained in the app

below my own json data structure if it is not correct please help me.

```
        {
    "Introduction": [



        {
            "image": "https://www.google.se/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic0_Cw6Z7eAhXEjiwKHXA8AMkQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.truelancer.com%2Ffreelancer%2Fyodgorbekkomilov&psig=AOvVaw3mvKiQhQ9gtIiyB0sX4cSQ&ust=1540461755427608",
            "introduction": "Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.",

        }
    ],


    "Education": [

        {
            "duration": "2012-2014",
            "institution": "Riga Technical University Latvia, Riga",
            "degree": "Bachelor Degree in Computer Science",

        },
    ],

    "Work": [

        {
            "company": "Udacity",
            "duration": " Jun 2018 - Present ",
            "responsibility": "Android Project Reviewer",

        },


        {
            "company": "Mobi Verse",
            "duration": " Jan 2018 - Present",
            "responsibility": "Developing Android apps for US market",

        },

        {
            "company": "Freelancer",
            "duration": " Jan 2017 - Present",
            "responsibility": "Developing  eCommerce  and different various android apps",

        },

        {
            "company": "Softwerk AB",
            "duration": " December 2016 - May 2017",
            "responsibility": " Maintaining existing Android apps",

        },
    ],

    "Skills": [

        {
            "Programming": "Java, C Sharp, Kotlin, Swift",
            "Framework/Libraries": "Android, IOS",
            "Android Architecture Components": "Live Data, ViewModel, Room",
            "Software Methodologies": "Agile, Scrum, Waterfall",
            "IDE'S": "Eclipse, Android Studio, Xcode",



        },
    ],
    "Contact": [

        {
            "Linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/edgar-sweden/",
            "gmail": "kyodgorbek@gmail.com",
            "phone number": "+46760981871",




        },
    ],
}

}






}
```

Comment: Use an object for key value pairs, an array to contain lists of stuff, strings for text, and numbers for numbers. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @ Can you make in json format I am android developer but never created by myself

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you help with that

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Remember, JSON isn't a programming language, it's a way of formatting data.

Comment: @evolutionxbox,I  know I have never  created json rest api by myself but now I need your guidance

Comment: API? I thought you were asking to format JSON data...

Comment: I need create my own json data and have to use mocky.io

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I will have created my own json sctructure please check it my updated post

Comment: You can use a tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to check that your JSON is technically valid. Currently what you've shown is invalid - there are stray brackets lurking around.

Comment: P.S. I don't see why you've made Introduction an array - you'd only use an array if you wanted to include more than one object of the same kind. I assume you're only one person and only have one image and introduction...so you can make Introduction a single object instead. Education makes sense as an array though, since you will be showing multiple items of history (and in the question it says it must be a list, so there's a clue for you).It's somewhat a matter of opinion though...there's never one "right" answer, you just need something which allows you to present the information required.

Comment: @ADyson can you check I have updated my json data give me some suggestion

Comment: can someone check my post please

Comment: only the Education and Work items needs to be arrays as far as I can see, because they're the only ones which require a repeating list of items. The rest can just be flat objects. But at the end of the day, it's still primarily a matter of opinion. The information required is conveyed by your example, but just possibly not in the most efficient way.